# Skip over 'n' iterations in Enumerable#each_cons

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to skip `n` iterations while executing an `each` block?

```
persons.each_cons(2) do |person|
  if person[0] == person[1]
    #SKIP 2 iterations
  end

  puts "Howdy? #{person[0]}"
end
```

Answer (score 4):

**Just use the `Enumerator` explicitly:**

```
persons = [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3]
enum = persons.each_cons(2)

loop do
  p1, p2 = enum.next
  if p1 == p2
    2.times { enum.next }
  else
    puts "Howdy? #{p1}"
  end
end
```

---

---

**Some notes:**

- All loops (such as `while`, `for`, `loop`) already rescue `StopIteration` by default by `break`ing (surprise surprise), making `next`ing super easy
- Explicit use of `Enumerator` is as Ruby as it gets! Grab a *recent* copy of the Ruby Pickaxe book, browse to chapter 4.3 (Blocks and Iterators) and enjoy!
- Don't miss out on parallel assignments, even in blocks
- If you have trouble navigating an `Enumerable` just the way you want, I suggest taking 10 minutes to read the module documentation: many could find the difference between `#each_cons` and `#each_slice` as enlightening as I did.
  Particularly, do review at least all methods *names* starting with `chunk`, `drop`, `each` and `slice` (more suggestions welcome in the comments!). Having to call `#next` by hand is actually rare.

---

**Bonus points:**

Knowledge of the difference between "iterator" and `Enumerator` (same Pickaxe chapter as mentioned above) actually does come in handy.
Sometimes your conundrum is better addressed by building a custom iterator:

```
persons = [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3]
custom_iter = Enumerator.new do |yielder|
  en = persons.each_cons(2)
  loop do
    2.times { en.next } while (p1, p2 = en.next).reduce(:==)
    yielder.yield p1
  end
end

custom_iter.each { |pers| puts "Howdy? #{pers}" }
```

Why should you learn about custom iterators? Imagine you need to operate on arbitrarily large (note the `#lazy`) sets of even numbers:

```
def Integer.even from:0
  Enumerator.new do |yielder, n: (from.even? ? from : from+1 )|
    loop { yielder.yield n; n += 2}
  end.lazy
end

p Integer.even(from: 3).take(10).to_a
```

Ruby's way of exposing element enumeration rather than list iteration can change the way you think about sequences and collections -- give it a chance ;)

Comment: **Footnote:** the free online version of the [Ruby Pickaxe book](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/) is for Ruby 1.6, and does not offer the mentioned in-depth discussion of "iterator", `Enumerator` and `Enumerable`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that directly.

You probably want to call [`uniq`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-uniq) on your array, or if order is important, check out the new [`chunk`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) method:

```
[1,1,1,2,1,3].uniq # => [1,2,3]
[1,1,1,2,1,3].chunk{|e| e}.map(&:first) # => [1,2,1,3]
# i.e. two adjacent items will always be different
```

Comment: using `uniq` is not an option since `persons` is an array of arrays (CSV) and some of the columns are DateTime values so no two rows are exactly identical.
Can you elaborate on the second way? (How/what does it do)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it, which is not really ruby like, is to use the `each` iterator.

```
persons = [1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,7,8,9]

persons_iterator = persons.each
begin
  while first_person = persons_iterator.next do
    second_person = persons_iterator.next
    if first_person == second_person
      persons_iterator.next.next # Skip 2 iterations
    end

    puts "Howdy? #{first_person}"
  end
rescue StopIteration
  # Iterator end
end
```